# Good resources for learning base R

Tags: r

So as I continue to use R, or any coding language for that matter, I like the idea of learning that coding language without additional libraries first then add libraries as needed.

My question is, are there any good resources for coding only in Base R? As a specific example I forgot how to count the occurrence of a character string in a specific column in a data frame. The column was State & I want to count for example how many times the word Texas appears in that column.

Because I forgot the function names that would be useful to doing this task I can't just look on the help section in R-studio hence why I wanted to find a good resource for base R. Even if it's just a list of functions & their general description would be helpful (because then I could just use ctrl+f to find key words).

If you really want to know why I like learning coding without extensions, libraries, etc first it's because I think I can trust that the base functions will be less susceptible to change through time & should be maintained and/or upgraded more regularly.

Comment: See "Help" pane of RStudio if you are using it, press home button then "An Introduction to R" under manuals. Or read the [.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) from CRAN.

Comment: +1 for trying to stay simple and "base". Solutions may take a bit more coding compared with using a library, but it's worth the time imho. The reward is a deep understanding of the language, but you have to invest some time - there are not many shortcuts.

Comment: some links https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Ryan. My favorite "base R" resource is [Norman Matloff](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/matloff.html)'s [The Art of R Programming](https://www.amazon.com/Art-Programming-Statistical-Software-Design/dp/1593273843/).